Standard Method of Supporting Vendors Using C++ and Premake
I am working on a template that makes use of Premake and GoogleTest, but I am having issues finding any documentation on a standardized method of implementing Premake. The source that I have been using to design my workspace places a core Build.lua that connects to secondary Build.lua files inside each individual project in the workspace.
Would it be considered better implementation to place a Build.lua into the GoogleTest Repository, even if it isn't locally managed? Would it be better to create an all encompassing Build.lua file for all vendors within my vendor directory? Or should I place individual build files outside of my vendor repositories, even if it breaks my current standards? Is there a solution that I am not considering that could resolve this without any of the aforementioned drawbacks?
I have attempted placing a Build.lua file inside of the vendor's directory - however, I was concerned that this was a bad practice as it could cause interferences if I needed to update the repository in the future, and it could be misleading to individuals that recognize the vendor and assume the repository to be a mirror of the vendor's.

BTW, it is not premake specific, that question happen to any build system.

I tend to let 3rd party intact (generally retrieved via submodule or equivalent) and have the script in the parent directory managing all 3rd party dependencies.

@Jarod42 Added build tag.

@Jarod42 I could understand the use of 3rd party interaction, though I don't know if it is possible or feasable given the situation in which I'm running the software.
I am currently using Visual Studio Code as an IDE, and I am essentially containerizing the system using WSL. It's possible that I could use Visual Studio, though, beyond personal preference, (1 I don't know if I can interface with my WSL as easily, (2 I can't guarantee other users will use the same environment, and a lot of Visual Studio Features aren't supported by other editors.
Plus, who doesn't love trial by fire?

For anyone else who sees this - the solution I'm using for the time being is as follows.
Instead of saving GoogleTest as GoogleTest, I am saving GoogleTest as GoogleTest/src and saving my build file as GoogleTest/Build-GoogleTest.lua.
